# IBM Liberty Access Logging

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

Worklight 5.0.5
Liberty 8.5.0.1

We are experiencing some timeout problems, i see in the liberty infocenter it says that you can turn on access logging on liberty with

```
<httpAccessLogging/>
```

and with

```
<httpAccessLogging enabled="true" filePath="e:\\Temp\\http_access.log" />
```

I have inserted the tag in my server.xml, but it does not create an access log file.
The main thing im looking for the is the IP address of the device that is making the call.
That was i can find out if the call made it to the server at a certain time..

Answer (score 0):

httpAccessLogging is enabled on a per-httpEndpoint basis.  Try:

```
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint">
  <accessLogging/>
</httpEndpoint>
```

...or:

```
<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" accessLoggingRef="hal"/>
<httpAccessLogging id="hal"/>
```

Comment: I put it in my httpEndpoint Definitions:  `<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" 
                  host="*" 
                  httpPort="9080" 
                  httpsPort="9443" > 
  <accessLogging filepath="e:\\Temp\\http_access.log" />
        <tcpOptions soReuseAddr="true"/> 
    
    </httpEndpoint>`   but still no file created